# Syncing postgres instances with mongo db in a Django project

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql, mongo-connector

Please i am working on a Django project that uses postgres as it primary database. Now I have been tasked with syncing the postgres instances with mongo db but I don’t know how to go about it. I cant find any real resources out there. The idea is that the data in the mongo db should always match  what’s in the postgres db. If a row in the postgres db is deleted, created or updated, it should sync to the mongo db. Chat gpt recommended pymongo and mongo-connector to do the syncing but nth seems to be working

I pip installed pymongo and mongo-connector, then I was told to create a config.yml in my project root directory, fill up the config file with the necessary configurations and then run mongo-connector -m config.yml. But I get an error